# jquery tab cookie ...?

Tags: php, jquery

Hy ,

I have the following code for mai tabs ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#continut_right div.tab").hide();
    $("#continut_right div.tab:first-child").show();

    $("#navigatie_left ul li").click(function() {
        var id_tab = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#continut_right div.tab").hide();
        $("#continut_right").children("#" + id_tab).show();
    });
```

and the markup is something like this :

```
<div id="continut_right">
   <!-- tab 1 -->       
   <div class="tab" id="id1"> 
   content ... bla bla bla
   </div>
</div>
```

and the menu that trigger  tabs to change :

```
<div id="navigatie_left">
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color:#000; font-family:Arial; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">[ REFRESH ]</a>
        <br /><br />
        <ul>
            <li id="id1">Categorii principale</li>
            <li id="id2">Categorii secundare</li>
            <li id="id2">Texte categorii secundare</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How can i implement a code ... to remember what tab was opened because when i do a form submit to php_self to keep that tab open to see changes ... ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not using jquery UI because i developed my own TABs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into .appendTo()'s [JSON Cookie](http://code.appendto.com/plugins/jquery-jsoncookie) solution. it would offer an easy method of storing and retrieving the last-active tab.

The usage is [documented](http://code.appendto.com/plugins/jquery-jsoncookie/docs) as follows:

```
$.cookie( string key, mixed value [, hash options ] )
```

So you could store the index of the active tab:

```
$.cookie( 'activeTab', '3' );
```

And then retrieve it on page load with:

```
$.cookie( 'activeTab' ); //returns the set value
```

So let's look at how you could implement it:

```
$("#navigatie_left ul li").click(function() {
    var id_tab = $(this).attr("id");
    $.cookie( 'activeTab', id_tab ); // storing the new active tab
    $("#continut_right div.tab").hide();
    $("#continut_right").children("#" + id_tab).show();
});
```

Now for us to automatically show the tab on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#continut_right div.tab").hide();
    $("#continut_right div.tab:first-child").show();
    // Which tab should we show on document.ready?
    $("#continut_right").children("#" + $.cookie('activeTab')).show();

});
```

Comment: @pufos No; just store the index in your click method. And when the page loads check for an index stored, and if you find one, trigger the click on that tab.

Comment: where did u find this on api.jquery.com ... there is nothing written about this ..

Comment: @pufos This is a took offered by a jQuery-focused company called .appendTo(). You can find the tool online at http://code.appendto.com/plugins/jquery-jsoncookie/docs

Comment: @pufos Yes. It's a professionally-built plugin by some of the smartest jQuery developers I know :)

Comment: One more thing ... I have about 20 pages in wich i use that TAB markup ... if the client is o tab2 in xy.php ... will it be opened in abc.php if i use the same tab markup ??? can I make a difference ??

Comment: @pufos You can set specific keys if you like. Suppose you have an index page and a gallery page with tabs. You could store the last active tab for each like this `$.cookie('indexTab', '3');` and `$.cookie('galleryTab', '12');` If use the same key, you'll create ambiguity and ultimately confuse the experience for the user.

Comment: You could construct the cookie key from a body class, too. So your index page is `<body class='index'>` and your gallery page is `<body class='gallery'>`; so when you wish to call your `$.cookie()` instance, you pass in the `$("body").attr("class")` as the key. This would keep your keys distinct for each page without requiring you to change your jQuery code up for each page.

Comment: Hy ... i run the test.html and it said `2 tests of 14 passed, 12 failed.` in Chrome

Comment: So how to check if it has a $.cookie set to show the tab containig $.cookie id ... or else to show the `first-child` ?

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST ... i figure it out .. and now it's working like a charm .. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window.location.hash` to store the current tab id. You have to write code that reads the `window.location.hash` property for the tab id on `$(document).ready()` and automatically switch to that tab.

An example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id_tab = window.location.hash;
    $("#continut_right div.tab").hide();
    if(id_tab){
       $("#continut_right").children(id_tab).show();
    }else{
       $("#continut_right div.tab:first-child").show();
    }
    $("#navigatie_left ul li").click(function() {
        var id_tab = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#continut_right div.tab").hide();
        $("#continut_right").children("#" + id_tab).show();
        window.location.hash = id_tab;
    });

});
```

Comment: I have no clue on how to do that

Comment: @pufos I've added an example to help you understand.